# Missing taskbar buttons on Taskbar in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, taskbar, sp2

My Windows XP only show Taskbar without taskbar buttons. I can change Task Windows using Alt+Tab Keys. In task Manager, there is show All open windows and task. But Missing taskbar buttons on taskbar.

I've already repaired windows by "second R". But still missing taskbar buttons. If I reinstall windows, then I will lost all software program install on that windows XP. I don't want to reinstall all software program after windows installation.

How do I get the taskbar bottons to show on the taskbar without reinstalling? Other toolbars on taskbar are OK. Only missing task windows-buttons.

Posted by Theo (1 messages posted)

Hi! Whenever you run a program in Windows, there should be a respective taskbar button right? This is for the user to access the running program faster by clicking on it and it will become the active window. My taskbar buttons disappeared. Now I can only use Alt-Tab to switch between programs. Anyone with ideas?

Comment: First read FAQ (http://superuser.com/faq) Super User is collaboratively built and maintained by users from around the world. thus, asking in English is the most common

Comment: asking in English is, in fact, required (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow), but including a translation of the question in another language is not prohibited.  (that said, i can't even see the characters, just those funky unicode blocks.  what is that, myanmar?)

Comment: yes.. it's Myanmar. also I know that guy too .. bad ;S

Comment: I'll be careful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a registry problem - you can use the script below to repair this problem. Copy all the following text and paste into a text file. Save with a .vbs extension and run.

```
Set WSHShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Message = "To work correctly, the script will close" & vbCR
Message = Message & "and restart the Windows Explorer shell." & vbCR
Message = Message & "This will not harm your system." & vbCR & vbCR
Message = Message & "Continue?"

X = MsgBox(Message, vbYesNo, "Notice")

If X = 6 Then 

On Error Resume Next

WshShell.RegDelete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StuckRects2\"
WshShell.RegDelete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StreamMRU\"
WshShell.RegDelete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams\Desktop\"

WshShell.RegDelete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Explorer Bars\{32683183-48a0-441b-a342-7c2a440a9478}\BarSize"

P1 = "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\"

WshShell.RegWrite p1 & "NoBandCustomize", 0, "REG_DWORD"
WshShell.RegWrite p1 & "NoMovingBands", 0, "REG_DWORD"
WshShell.RegWrite p1 & "NoCloseDragDropBands", 0, "REG_DWORD"
WshShell.RegWrite p1 & "NoSetTaskbar", 0, "REG_DWORD"
WshShell.RegWrite p1 & "NoToolbarsOnTaskbar", 0, "REG_DWORD"
WshShell.RegWrite p1 & "NoSaveSettings",0,"REG_DWORD"
WshShell.RegWrite p1 & "NoToolbarsOnTaskbar", 0, "REG_DWORD"
WshShell.RegWrite p1 & "NoSetTaskbar",0,"REG_DWORD"
WshShell.RegWrite p1 & "NoActiveDesktop",0,"REG_DWORD"
WshShell.RegWrite p1 & "ClassicShell",0,"REG_DWORD"

p1 = "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy Objects\LocalUser\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\"

WshShell.RegWrite p1 & "NoCloseDragDropBands", 0, "REG_DWORD"
WshShell.RegDelete p1 & "NoMovingBands"

p1 = "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell"

WshShell.RegWrite p1, "explorer.exe", "REG_SZ"

p1 = "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Explorer Bars\{32683183-48a0-441b-a342-7c2a440a9478}\"
WshShell.RegDelete p1 & "BarSize"
WshShell.RegWrite p1, "Media Band", "REG_SZ"

On Error Goto 0

For Each Process in GetObject("winmgmts:"). _
    ExecQuery ("select * from Win32_Process where name='explorer.exe'")
   Process.terminate(0)
Next

MsgBox "Finished.", 4096, "Done"

Else

MsgBox "No changes were made to your system.", 4096, "User Cancelled"

End If
```

Comment: I'll test when I back home,